# How to initialize a large number of variables in Java quickly and easily?

Tags: java

So I have a really basic coding question, I just started learning this year, and I have an assignment for a code that is supposed to

> flip a fair coin n times and count how many heads it gets. The program will do m experiments and then
>   print out the results as a (vertical) histogram. The program will first ask the user to input the number of
>   experiments to perform (m) and the number of coin flips in each experiment (n). n can be at most 79. The
>   output will be a histogram made up of spaces and asterisks (*), with n+1 columns (for the number of heads
>   which can go from 0 to n)

I have the code for the histogram all done, but the problem I have is how to store the number of heads as it's own variable. For example, if it flipped the coin 80 times and 40 of them were heads, I would want it to create an int for 40 flips, then add one to it. I just don't know how to go about initializing 80 variables without writing out int one = 0; int two = 0, int three = 0; until the end of time, then writing 80 if statements until it finds the right integer to add one to. Is there an easy way to do this or should there be a different approach I should be taking? Here is the code, please be gentle, literally only a month or so into an extremely basic java class

```
 for(m=m; m>0; m--) { //runs m number of experiments of n coinflips, keeping track of total heads
   n = o; // when N gets set to 0 through the while loop, o resets it back to it's original so it can loop again
   while(n>0) {
     n--;
     if(random.nextBoolean()) {
       heads++;
       total++;
       /** here is where I want the number of heads saved to a
       variable, so that way later I can run a loop to put as many *'s as I need in the histogram later */
```

Comment: Title says Java, but the only tag is javascript. **Not** the same thing.

Comment: Java and JavaScript are different worlds. Did you put the wrong tag?

Comment: please add your code, you have, to the question and have a look here [mcve].

Comment: Have you thought about creating an array and then pushing the result to it?  For example `var result = []; result.push(Heads); results.push(Tails);` where Heads and Tails are constants unique values.

Comment: @vbguyny. Besides the fact that you are making a bunch of non-Java statements about arrays, very good idea.

Comment: @vbguyny I assume your comment was made before the JavaScript tag was removed. The suggestion is still good, but it would be using a list in Java (probably `ArrayList`)

Comment: You only need *one* variable to hold the number of, say, "heads". The number of tails is then `(numberOfExperiments - countOfHeads)`.

Comment: Fixed the Java/javascript thing, sorry I just started learning to code like a month ago.

Comment: You do need to post some code tho

Comment: Sorry just figured out how to format the code on this site. First time using it, again apologies

Comment: @Algorn120 Now, after I read your question again, I think you don't even need to use array. Can't you print the histogram as you generate the results?

Comment: @user3437460 Possibly? let me try and get back to you, I might be able to. Edit: Just tried to, but I can't quite figure it out. Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an array for the 80 (or n) experiments:

> I don't understand, this would just count how many heads/tails there are right? This doesn't save them (ie it flipped 5 heads 6 times, 4 heads 3 times, 3 heads twice, ect) unless I'm misunderstanding

If you are storing the number of head `m` times (where `m` is < 80), you can:

1) print the histogram as you generate the results (no array needed) **OR**

2) store the 80 results in an array

---

**Example for 1 (no array):**

```
for(int x=0; x<experiments; x++){
    int heads = 0;
    for(int y=0; y<flips; y++){
        if(rnd.nextInt(2) == 0)    //assume 0 is head    
            heads ++;
    }        
    //print histogram
    for(int y=0; y<heads; y++)
        System.out.print("*");
    System.out.println();
}
```

**Example for 2 (with array):**

```
int[] expr = new int[80];    //store results for 80 experiments
for(int x=0; x<expriments; x++)
    for(int y=0; y<flips; y++)
        if(rnd.nextInt(2) == 0)
            expr[x] ++;
```

Comment: I don't understand, this would just count how many heads/tails there are right? This doesn't save them (ie it flipped 5 heads 6 times, 4 heads 3 times, 3 heads twice, ect) unless I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: Not sure how to delete a comment, tried to say something and confused myself.

Comment: Using the code you provided, expr[1] for example would then hold the number of times heads was flipped only once right, expr[2] for 2 heads? If so that's a huge help, I didn't think of using an array!

Comment: @Algorn120 Look at my last edited solution. If it helps, you may accept ***one*** solution from here which helped you most (by clicking the hollow looking tick beside the solution).

Comment: Thanks! Example 2 is exactly what I needed, accepted your answer! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Use an array:

```
int n = 80;

// space for n integers, with indexes 0..n
int[] histogram = new int[n + 1]; 

for (int i = 0; i < experiments; i++) {
    // flip coin n times, counting heads
    int heads = ...;

    histogram[heads] = histogram[heads] + 1;
}

for (int i = 0; i < histogram.length; i++) {
    printStars(histogram[i]);
}
```

If you're unfamiliar with arrays, [the Java Tutorial has a good explanation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).